# Regex: capture group of max number of sequential defined words

Tags: regex

regex: `cat|dog|mouse|fish`

on

text: `dog cat`

captures a group with 2 matches. I would like a group with a single match of "dog cat".

I tried `[cat|dog|mouse|fish]+` but still 2 matches, and also matches other things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an optional `\s` or `\s*` before the pattern and make it to repeat one or more times.

```
\b(?:\s?(?:cat|dog|mouse|fish))+
```

`[cat|dog|mouse|fish]` is the wrong way of matching group of characters. You need to put those substrings inside a group not inside a character class.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ4hV3/2)

**OR**

```
(?<nnn>\b(?:cat|dog|mouse|fish)(?:\s+(?:cat|dog|mouse|fish)\b)*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ4hV3/6)

Comment: or `\b(?:\s?(?:cat|dog|mouse|fish))+\b`

Comment: Initally, looks like exactly what I need. 

2 problems: I added named capture until I add in named capture then it seem to get only the last one. Also capturing leading space which is not desired.  [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ4hV3/3)

Comment: Was able to fix named group with [DEMO] (https://regex101.com/r/rJ4hV3/5), now just have to figure out how not to include leading space